# Find the region where the function $f(z) = -i \sqrt z$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the region where the function $f(z) = -i \sqrt z$ is analytic, where $\sqrt z$ is the principle branch of the square root.

I face lots of difficulty to find the region of analyticity of $f$. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But @quasi in my book it has been stated that the principal square root function has the branch cut $\{-R : R \geq 0 \}$ and each point on that branch cut is a point of discontinuity of the function.

Comment: People should understand that "principle" and "principal" are different words, despite stemming from the same semantic root.

Comment: How is this any different from asking for the region where the function $g(z)=\sqrt z$ is analytic? What is the point of the constant factor?